# Help needed with android app code

Tags: android

I'm looking to make a new type app that when the user open it for the first time it will open up a pop-up menu that contains multiple check boxes that the user can select from and will then save their selections for later use. After the user selects their choices I would like to have a monthly based calender on this same screen that the user can select a date from and based on their selection this will then take them to a separate screen showing the news for that day.

I am fairly new to android app development and this will be my first go at it. I have read several books and websites but cannot seem to find the help I need to produce the code for the above desired functions. Any and all help with this will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Read these tutorials and you'll be able to create just what you need

[Tutorials](http://developer.android.com/resources/browser.html?tag=tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very vague in fact, so I will only suggest a few points to start reading from, that I believe are important.

I think that you will answer any other questions you may have by reading through the developer documents for Android and studying the supplied examples. But don't hesitate to ask another, more specific question if you run into trouble.

tl;dr

- [Activities](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html) (must read!)
- [Dialogs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) (you will need these)
- [Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) (also important for the app you describe)

If you're still lost, just get some sample code from the repository and toy with it.

Good luck!